# How can I unit test async database calls without changing the route?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, routes, mocha.js

So I have a route with a database call in a separate file:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const sql = `SELECT Topic FROM surveys WHERE ID="${req.params.id}"`;
  model.connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
    res.send(result);
  });
};
```

In my test file, I create fake req and res objects to test different inputs:

```
const req = {
  body: {},
  params: {
  id: '',
  }
};

const res = {
  message: '',
  stat: 200,
  send(arg) {
     this.message = arg;
  },
  status(number) {
     this.stat = number;
     return this;
  }
};
```

And call it in every test:

```
 it('Should return status 200 if parameter is a number string', () => {
   req.params.id = '1';
   getTopic(req, res);
   chai.expect(res.stat).to.equal(200);
 });
```

My question is, how can I test it asynchronously, without **affecting my route**?
I've seen Mocha documentation explaining this, but they require a callback in a function.

```
it('Should return status 200 if parameter is a number string', (done) => {
   req.params.id = '1';
   getTopic(req, res); // Cannot give any callback
   chai.expect(res.stat).to.equal(200);
   done(); //Doesn't work
});
```

I also tried using `async/await`, but it didn't work (I lack knowledge of how to use it, maybe that's why)

```
it('Should return status 200 if parameter is a number string', async () => {
   req.params.id = '1';
   await getTopic(req, res);
   chai.expect(res.stat).to.equal(200);
});
```

And I've seen this question, and didn't help at all: [unit testing express route with async callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721082/unit-testing-express-route-with-async-callback)

Comment: If you want to test the behavior of an actual express route that is acting "in the wild" (i.e. it's talking to an actual database) your best bet is to actually run the server and then make requests against it.  That's not a  unit test, it's more of a functional test or integration test.  https://scotch.io/tutorials/test-a-node-restful-api-with-mocha-and-chai

Comment: @Paul Thanks, the article and your response actually helped me.